# Installing ibplugin in Xcode 4 on Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

How can I install an ibplugin in Xcode 4 under Mac OS X Snow Leopard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The release notes hint that this is not possible. They state that you can build IB files containing plugin stuff but not edit them, IIRC.

Comment: But I'm not able to build them either...  :(